# Can not create table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have removed `users` table in my database and imported another `users` table.

It show this error:

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_group_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `national_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `eco_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `national_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `post_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci[...]
MySQL said: Documentation

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

My framwork is Laravel 5.6, PHP 7.2

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Were there any errors when you deleted the first `users` table?  But before you even answer that, why did you feel the need to completely delete/drop the table?  This error is often caused by having dependent records which are pointing to a parent table record which no longer exists.

Comment: are you using laravel migrations to do this or just a raw sql query?

Comment: @Rafee I work with migration but i remove `users` table in phpmyadmin...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen After remove `users` table in phpmyadmin, I can't create new table with `users` name !

Comment: Yes, we know this because you already told us.

Comment: do you have migration file of users table?

Comment: run `php artisan migrate` command

Comment: can you update your question with execution steps you are doing and what files you have?

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with migrations, you have to make every change in database through migrations. You can make changes in the existing users_table migration file. You can drop/add column/table using artisan command. Migrations in Laravel can do every interaction with the database. Take your time to go thorugh all the basics of migrations if you don't know:
[Laravel Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations)

Answer (score 0):

Use migration in laravel. It is better that way and check the migration field in your table. May be the previous migrations will still be there